# a tag, or css property that will make tag invisible to flex

Tags: css, flexbox

Having an html like this:

```
<div class='flexcont'>
   <div class='wrap'>
      <div class='item'>
         cont1
      </div>
      <div class='item'>
         cont2
      </div>
   <div>
</div>
```

I would like the flexbox to ignore the presence of `.wrap`, as if it wasn't there.

Is this possible ?

Comment: do you want to hide it?

Comment: no, the `.wrap` `div` is only necessary for a js framework to define a component, but it breaks the flex flow

Comment: maybe you can flex the .wrap div to achieve what you want

Comment: @DovRine this is one possibility, I wanted to know if I can avoid that

Comment: @buga: you might be able to replace flexbox with grid. That way, you can just grid on .item and ignore .wrap completely

Comment: @DovRine thanks, guess the answer is No it isn't possible, there's no invisible tag, only if  I give up on flex and switch to grid, for the moment I handled my actual problem with js